# Does a vaccine reduce the contagion "efficiency"?

Tags: vaccination, infection, covid

*Note: I am specifically interested in the question in the context of COVID, but general information is welcome as well.*

If someone vaccinated still catches the COVID, is their capacity to infect others smaller, the same, or higher compared to someone not vaccinated?

In other words, is there a relationship between the "efficiency" of infecting others and the fact that someone was vaccinated (but still got infected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual case will be different, but in general it is useful to ask "why did the vaccinated person still catch the Covid disease?"

If they caught the disease because the vaccine had essentially no effect on them (for example, some immunocomprimised individuals who cannot generate an appropriate immune response), then they are likely to be at least as contagious as an unvaccinated individual. In fact, they may carry a higher viral load and be more infectious because of their underlying impaired immune response.

It's clear now that those who are vaccinated and successfully develop a targeted immune response against the covid virus (almost everyone for the two current mRNA vaccines), tend to have lower viral loads even if they are infected with the covid virus. This is presumably the reason why the incidence and severity of Covid disease is dramatically lower among vaccinees. The lower viral loads do indeed lessen the chance of infecting others with the covid virus, but do not completely eliminate it.

Comment: Thank you. What exactly does "virus load" mean? Is it an absolute number of the "amount of viruses" - that is there are fewer individual viruses, which all keep the same capacities of infection (so the lowered contagion is because of fewer viruses, and there are statistically less chances to get in contact with one), OR are the viruses "weakened" (possibly being as numerous as in a normal infection), so the lowered contagion would be because even if they get to the target, they are not as "powerful" as normally? (sorry for the non-technical terms)

Comment: @WoJ Your first answer is right -- virus load just means the number of virions (mature, infectious virus particles).  With the immune system responding well, fewer cells get infected, leading to lesser disease symptoms and also to reduced production of new virus particles.